# dropdown list event is not firing when javascript is used

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a problem in firing a dropdownlist event.

I have the following dropdown:

```
asp:dropdownlist id="ddlhello" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  onchange="javascript:return ChangeHeader();"
```

I have also added an event in the code behind i.e. selectedindex change event.

Now the problem occurs when I execute the page: it executes javascript but the server side code does not fire. If I remove this line `onchange="javascript:return ChangeHeader();"` then the server side code fires.

When I checked the source page it shows me two `onchange` events associated:
one for javascript and other for server side.

I think that it is picking client side code and neglects server side.

I am not pretty sure, so I want to know the behavior reason.

And what is the way out for this.

I want server and client side code to be executed.
I have searched for solutions but I have not found any correct reason.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can not bind the server side event with dropdown, bind it with onselectedindexchanged

> onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlhello" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"   onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" onchange="javascript:return ChangeHeader();" </asp:dropdownlist>
```

Returning false from client stops the postback.

```
function ChangeHeader()
{
 //return false; // will stop the postback
  return true; //will cause postback
}
```

Comment: i have returned true still it is not firing event.

Answer (score 0):

Use like following instead of
onchange="return ChangeHeader();"
onchange="ChangeHeader();"

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Whoever down voted this for whatever reason, please provide a reason for that.